# toLocaleString broken on Chrome 88 on Android 7.1

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I have just found that on Chrome 88 using my Windows 10, that toLocaleString is working correctly.
However, on my android galaxy tab 2 i am getting an 'invalid date'
This is my code - https://jsfiddle.net/6o7L08df/3/

```
var myDate = new Date();
var x = myDate.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: "Australia/Sydney"});
alert(new Date(myDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "Australia/Sydney" })));
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: We also stumbled upon this browser bug and it seems to work on older Chrome versions (we tested that it works on Chrome 84). As far as I have investigated the issue, Chrome ignores the `locales` parameter and just uses the system one. So the "workaround" is to change the system language to `en-US` in your instance.

Comment: Related to this Chromium bug issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1169034
Chrome bug for Android - resolved.